# Command mqreply.c timeout

Tags: ibm-mq

We with my colleague built mqreply.sh from https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-rfhutil/tree/master/mqperf
But we don't suggest that command mqreply has timeout after which process with command is closed.

I attach our file with params for executing mqreply:

```
[header]
qname=DEV.QUEUE.1
qmgr=QM1
msgcount=10
msgtype=2
format="MQSTR"
codepage=1208
persist=0
replyq=DEV.QUEUE.2
sleeptime=1000
maxWaitTime=5
maxtime=60
waitTime=60
replyFilename=/tmp/msqtoload.dat
```

I try to set maxWaitTime and maxtime, waitTime, but it doesn't affect timeout for life of process.

Can you say how can I let mqreply doesn't close or maybe increase timeout?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop around the MQGET in the mqreply sample you link to does this:-

```
while ((compcode == MQCC_OK) && (0 == terminate) && ((0 == parms.totcount) || (msgsRead < parms.totcount)))
{
```

Also, the MQGET will only wait for 1 seconds. There is a comment thus:-

```
/* since we have a signal handler installed, we do not want to be in an MQGET for a long time */
```

This suggests that if you want to keep mqreply open and running for longer, you need to specify `msgcount` as a number bigger than 10.

Comment: I increase parameter *msgcount* to 10000, but mqreply also closed after 5 sec.

Comment: Perhaps you'll need to edit that while loop then? Do you know what compcode and reason code the final MQGET received?

Comment: Yes, you were right. We decide to change condition on while. Thank you.